# Reset again and persist the data of JqGrid Row in Editable mode when some error return from Server

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hcoh.png)In "successfunc" the else part should retain the row in editable mode ...

```
 var editparameters= {
                    "keys": true,
                    "oneditfunc": function () {
                        debugger;
                        $("select#" + arrprimarykey + "_StateName").val(rowData.StateCode);
                    },
                    "successfunc": function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        var msg = JSON.parse(data.responseText).Message;
                        var msgType = JSON.parse(data.responseText).MsgType;
                        if (msgType == "S") {
                            alert(msg);
                            $(CityMaster.idGrid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        } else {
                            alert(msg)
                           HERE RESTORE TO INLINE EDITABLE MODE THE ROW ,AGAIN IF ERROR RETURN FROM SERVER
                        }
                    },

                    "url": CityMaster.EditUrl,
                    "extraparam": {},
                    "aftersavefunc": function (data) {
                        debugger;
                    },
                    "errorfunc": null,
                    "afterrestorefunc": function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $(CityMaster.idGrid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    },
                    "restoreAfterError": true,
                    "mtype": "POST"
                }
                jQuery(CityMaster.idGrid).jqGrid('editRow', arrprimarykey, editparameters);
```

In "successfunc" the else part should retain the row in editable mode ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of reporting the error in jqGrid is setting an error status code of HTTP response. If will force executing of `errorfunc` for example in case of usage inline editing. If the server code *unable* to set error status code of HTTP response then jqGrid provides an alternative. The callback `successfunc` can be used to examine the response of the server. The `successfunc` should inform jqGrid whether the response is successful of now. The callback `successfunc` should return array `[true]` in case of successful response and return array with two elements: `[false, "error message to display the user"]` in case of the error. The callback `successfunc` get typically the error message from the response from the server.

**UPDATED:** You should of case use `restoreAfterError: false` (see `"restoreAfterError": true` in your current code) to prevent restoring the state of the row before starting inline editing.

Comment: you mean this way:if (msgType == "S") {
                        alert(msg);
                        $(CityMaster.idGrid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    } else {
                        alert(msg);
                        return [false, msg];
                    }

Comment: @shyamshankar: Almost so, but you need make some changes in the above code. First of all you should understand that `.trigger('reloadGrid')` works **synchronously**, So your above code will start and probably process the reloading of grid first and then returns from `.trigger('reloadGrid')` and will continue the current executing. I recommend you never use `.trigger('reloadGrid')` directly in your code and wrap it inside of `setTimeout` instead. It will allows to process the current callback till the end end only after that to start processing of `.trigger('reloadGrid')`.

Comment: @shyamshankar: the corresponding code could be something like: `if (msgType == "S") { alert(msg); setTimeout(function () {$(CityMaster.idGrid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');}, 0); return [true];  } else { alert(msg); return [false, msg]; }` You can replace the second parameter of `setTimeout` from `0` to `50` for example, but 0 should already work. Such code returns either `[true]` or `[false, msg]`, process `successfunc` till the end and only then start `setTimeout` which would trigger reloadGrid.

Comment: i want to set my JQGrid Row In INLINE editable mode ,when msgType return other than "S" from SERVER.

Comment: @shyamshankar: I see you made small error in your code. You use `restoreAfterError: true` instead of `restoreAfterError: false`. It's exactly the setting which informs jqGrid to restore the old values from the line (the state before starting inline editing) or to hold inline editing after displaying the error message. You have to combine correct implementation of `successfunc` (return `[false, msg]` in case of error) with the option `restoreAfterError: false`.