# Prevent JQGrid From Restoring Row After Unsuccessful Request

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid` to display grid data. For editing I am using `inline edit`. What I want is in case of `Error` response from sever when `POST` request is made, `not to restore the edited row`. I want the row to stay in `edit form` until the response is `without any error`. I have this example which is not working. I red about the same problem in this question [Reset again and persist the data of JqGrid Row in Editable mode when some error return from Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297270/reset-again-and-persist-the-data-of-jqgrid-row-in-editable-mode-when-some-error). What did I miss in my code ?

```
$(obj.grid).jqGrid('saveRow', eRowId, {
                        aftersavefunc: saveRow,
                        url: ...,
                        mtype: "POST",
                        "restoreAfterError": false,
                    });

var saveRow = function (rowid, response) {
            if (response.Error) {

            }
            else {
                return [false, "error message to display the user"];
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong callback of `saveRow`. You should use `successfunc` instead of `aftersavefunc`.

Comment: It works now, but the enter and esc does not work now. What could be wrong ?

Comment: @TheChampp: You should just use correct options. To have support of Enter and Esc you should call `editRow` (you don't included the call in your question) with the option `keys: true`.

Comment: @TheChampp: `keys:true` should be added to the options of `editRow`, not to `saveRow`. `editRow` can register `keydown` event handler and to force call of `saveRow` or `restoreRow` if the user press Enter or Esc key. `saveRow` don't support any `keys:true` option.